# Iterate over multiple list in java

Tags: java, java-8

While i am trying to convert below code snippet using java8 getting "Local variable sId defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final" error.

Existing code:

```
String sId = "";
String uId = "";
FinalResp resp = new FinalResp();
List<LiqResp> liqRespList = getResp.getLiqRespList();
for(LiqResp liqResp : liqRespList){
  List<ListOfAcq> listAcq = liqResp.getLiqList(); 
     for(ListOfAcq acqList : listAcq){
        List<Acq> acqs = acqList.getAcqList();
        for(Acq acq :acqs){
         if(sId.equalIgnoreCase(acq.getId()) || uId.equalIgnoreCase(acq.getId())){
           resp.setId(acqList.getId());
          }
       }
   }
}
return resp;
```

Below is the snippet which i tried to convert using java8:

```
String sId = "";
String uId = "";
FinalResp resp = new FinalResp();
List<LiqResp> liqRespList = getResp.getLiqRespList();
liqRespList.parallelStream.forEach(liqResp -> liqResp.getLiqList().parallelStream.
forEach(acqList->acqList.getAcqList().stream.map(acq -> {
return conversion(acq, acqList, sId,uId,resp); //getting error here as "Local variable sId 
                                           //defined in an enclosing scope must be final 
                                           // or effectively final"
})));

private FinalResp conversion(Acq acq, ListOfAcq acqList, String sId,String uId,FinalResp resp){
   if(sId.equalIgnoreCase(acq.getId()) || uId.equalIgnoreCase(acq.getId())){  
           resp.setId(acqList.getId());
          }
   return resp;
}
```

Performance wise is this correct approach.thanks in advance for help.

Comment: I don't think your original code compiles - you have `return resp;` outside of the scope of `resp`.  That means it's hard to tell exactly what you intend the converted code to do.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `parallelStream`?  Unless your data is huge, that's probably just going to slow your program down.  Additionally, it's really unclear how your "converted" code is doing the same thing as the original; what's `conversion` do?

Comment: @Kavin add sample data for reference.